# Darkvision sunlight penalty house rule?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, races, racial-traits

In a game I am preparing to DM, the party will contain a halfling rogue. The other 3 PCs are all fey types, so he will be the only PC without darkvision.

I am thinking of partially removing or ignoring darkvision. Others posts have already discussed this.  However, I am also wondering, would it be a good idea, if creatures/pcs with darkvision incurred some sort of perception penalty when exposed to full sunlight?

This will be my first 5e game and first time DMing (with more than one person) ever, so any thoughts on this are much appreciated.

Comment: What benefit would there be to removing darkvision?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as unclear, because we need to know what you are trying to accomplish by not only removing the benefits of darkvision but even making this otherwise beneficial ability a straightforward penalty. Providing this information would help us provide more helpful answers.

Comment: Icyfire, I hadn't thought about benefits. Thats a good question.

Comment: Kvirri, I guess I am looking for a more balanced or consistant approach to darkvision. If Drow get a penalty, why not everyone else?

Comment: Keep in mind that Darkvision is not simply "you can see in the dark" it lifts the level of illumination 1 step effectively. So in total darkness it goes to dim-light still incurring perception disadvantage. The reason the Drow and other deep races have the sensitivity is that they have not seen the sun for generations. Or if you go the slightly darker route (supported by lots of previous edition lore), Drow are essentially elven demonic tieflings since they were tainted by Lolth.

Comment: @James Young, Drow and Duergar get a penalty due to Superior Darkvision, which provides 120' instead of 60' visibility.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As a DM you are free (and encouraged) to tweak the game to your liking.

However, punishing players for their character building choices is bad. The player that made the halfling character probably had the option to choose another race with darkvision. Maybe not, but that is not the point.

There are several ways to mitigate the fact that one character cannot see in the dark. There are light sources, there are the [goggles of the night](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Goggles%20of%20Night#content) wondrous item, and other magic or spells to allow him to adventure with his fey friends.

A torch costs 1 coppper piece, and solves the problem. Almost all starter packs have a few included.

I'd advise against changing the game too much in the first few games you DM. It is better to learn the ropes with the out-of-box game before making your own changes. But again, it is your game. Never let the rules get in the way of your (and your friends players) fun.

As @Erik pointed out in the comments, there are several races that suffer penalties in daylight. Most of them are native to the underdark (a huge underground labyrinth covering all the world) and these penalties offset some very nice perks they get. So you shouldn't just slap these other darkvision races with a penalty without some kind of benefit in another area.

Comment: I would extend this with examples of races that _actually_ get penalties in sunlight, like Drow, to make it clear that this option already exists for some races and comes with some extra racial perks.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Didn't realize this already exists.